# windows batch script execution becomes interactive after using ftp

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, ftp

I am writing a .cmd Windows script to be run in batch mode. This script uses the ftp command. After a successsful connection to another machine using ftp, the shell changes, and the execution of the script becomes interactive.

How can I make it in batch mode, so as not to stop the execution of he whole script?

thanks.

Comment: Are you using the `-s` switch with ftp?

Comment: you´re right!! and also, the '-i' option is useful. See http://www.c3scripts.com/tutorials/msdos/ftp.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code for me:

```
ftp -i -n -s:%currentFolderPath%ftp_commands.txt %IPAddress%
```

Read:

[MS-DOS ftp command](http://www.c3scripts.com/tutorials/msdos/ftp.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `bye` to quit an ftp session to return to the batch.

Alternatively, put the ftp commands in a separate batch file and use `call` to call it.

```
rem do stuff
rem do ftp stuff
call ftpscript.bat
rem carry on doing stuff
```

Comment: I´ve tried this option, and invoking "call" also pauses the execution of the script.